# angularjs directive keeps converting array of arrays to one long string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array of arrays and when I pass it to the directive it keeps changing it to one long string. How do I avoid this from happening? I want to be able to loop thru the outer array in the directive.

My element in the view is like this:

```
        <big big-data="{{data.data}}" ng-if="data.data"></chart>
```

and my directive is set like this:

```
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
        bigData: '='
        },
     replace: false,
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       var data = attrs.bigData;
       console.log(data);

       ......
```

Comment: What if you take out the `{{ }}`?

Comment: having  bigData: '=' will hit and error if u pass the value there , you need to remove the {{}}

Comment: Use `=` for variable variables and `@` for literals strings.

Comment: if i remove the `{{ }}` it just shows `data.data`

Comment: change `attrs.bigData` to `scope.bigData` and change `{{data.data}}` to just `data.data`

Comment: It shows "data.data" because you're reading the attribute value not the scope two-way binding.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - yes that fixed it. Big thanks!